# Finding Aggregate Sum of entries in a LINQ expression

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate-functions

I have written a LINQ query that returns a set of objects(anon-type) based on the JOIN condition

```
var customerOrderResponse = tableOne.Join(
                    tableTwo,
                    firstData => firstData.BookingId,
                    secData => secData.OrderBookingId,
                    (firstData, secData) => new 
                    {
                        OrderNumber = firstData.Name,
                        Weight = firstData.Weight,
                        WeightUnit = firstData.WeightUnit,  //string = KG
                        Volume = firstData.Volume, 
                        VolumeUnit = firstData.VolumeUnit,   ////string = CUBIC-MTR
                        PackageQuantity = firstData.PackageQuantity,
                        PackageQuantityUnit = firstData.PackageQuantityUnit, // 
                        CustomerProductQuantity = firstData.CustomerProductQuantity,
                        CustomerProductQuantityUnit = firstData.CustomerProductQuantityUnit,
                        
                    }).GroupBy(co => co.CustomerOrderNumber).Select(s => s.First());
```

The LINQ query returns 0,1 or many entries of Anonymous type based on the join condition in the database.
My question is what needs to be modified in the query to get an **Aggregate Sum** of certain columns

For ex:

Weight = firstData.Weight,
Volume = firstData.Volume,
PackageQuantity = firstData.PackageQuantity,

How can I modify the above query to return it the expected way

Comment: Could you post sample data and expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the combined weight and volume of all items in a single customer order, you can do this like so:

```
var customerOrderResponse = tableOne.Join(
        tableTwo,
        firstData => firstData.BookingId,
        secData => secData.OrderBookingId,
        (firstData, secData) => new
        {
            OrderNumber = firstData.Name,
            Weight = firstData.Weight,
            WeightUnit = firstData.WeightUnit,  //string = KG
            Volume = firstData.Volume,
            VolumeUnit = firstData.VolumeUnit,   ////string = CUBIC-MTR
            PackageQuantity = firstData.PackageQuantity,
            PackageQuantityUnit = firstData.PackageQuantityUnit, // 
            CustomerProductQuantity = firstData.CustomerProductQuantity,
            CustomerProductQuantityUnit = firstData.CustomerProductQuantityUnit,

        }).GroupBy(co => co.OrderNumber)
        .Select(items => new
        {
            Items = items,
            TotalVolume = items.Sum(x => x.Volume), // beware of unit.
            TotalWeight = items.Sum(x => x.Weight), // beware of unit.
        })         
        .Select(s => s.First());
```

But make sure that adding volumes happen in the same unit, and then also keep track of that unit. Same goes for mass, etc...

To convert to a common unit, first pick a common unit and sum the converted values:

```
.Select((items) =>
{
    string commonVolumeUnit = items.FirstOrDefault()?.VolumeUnit;
    string commonWeightUnit = items.FirstOrDefault()?.WeightUnit;

    return new
    {
        Items = items,
        VolumeUnit = items.FirstOrDefault()?.VolumeUnit,
        WeightUnit = items.FirstOrDefault()?.WeightUnit,
        TotalVolume = items.Sum(x => ConvertVolume(x.Volume, x.VolumeUnit, commonVolumeUnit)),
        TotalWeight = items.Sum(x => ConvertWeight(x.Weight, x.WeightUnit, commonWeightUnit)),
    };
})
```

You can then access each individual item by the Items property of the new anonymous type.

When the item source is an enumerable (not a list, nor an array, etc), it might be best to 'buffer' the items as a list:

```
.Select((items) =>
{
    var itemsList = items.ToList();

    string commonVolumeUnit = itemsList.FirstOrDefault()?.VolumeUnit;
    string commonWeightUnit = itemsList.FirstOrDefault()?.WeightUnit;

    return new
    {
        Items = itemsList,
        VolumeUnit = commonVolumeUnit ,
        WeightUnit = commonWeightUnit ,
        TotalVolume = itemsList.Sum(x => ConvertVolume(x.Volume, x.VolumeUnit, commonVolumeUnit)),
        TotalWeight = itemsList.Sum(x => ConvertWeight(x.Weight, x.WeightUnit, commonWeightUnit)),
    };
})
```

For completeness: Here is my full test code for the above: (on fiddle, so you can test: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gYOzrg)

---

**EDIT: Since you want all Properties within one object; you can do this like so:** (also on fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DWORbJ)

```
var customerOrderResponse =
    tableOne.Join(
        tableTwo,
        firstData => firstData.BookingId,
        secData => secData.OrderBookingId,
        (firstData, secData) => new
        {
            FirstData = firstData,
            SecondData = secData,
            OrderNumber = firstData.Name,
            Weight = firstData.Weight,
            WeightUnit = firstData.WeightUnit,  //string = KG
            Volume = firstData.Volume,
            VolumeUnit = firstData.VolumeUnit,   ////string = CUBIC-MTR
            PackageQuantity = firstData.PackageQuantity,
            PackageQuantityUnit = firstData.PackageQuantityUnit, // 
            CustomerProductQuantity = firstData.CustomerProductQuantity,
            CustomerProductQuantityUnit = firstData.CustomerProductQuantityUnit,

        }).GroupBy(co => co.OrderNumber)

        .Select((items) =>
        {
            var itemsList = items.ToList();

            string commonVolumeUnit = itemsList[0].VolumeUnit;
            string commonWeightUnit = itemsList[0].WeightUnit;

            return new
            {
                Items = itemsList,
                TotalVolume = itemsList.Sum(x => ConvertVolume(x.Volume, x.VolumeUnit, commonVolumeUnit)),
                TotalWeight = itemsList.Sum(x => ConvertWeight(x.Weight, x.WeightUnit, commonWeightUnit)),
                TotalVolumeUnit = commonVolumeUnit,
                TotalWeightUnit = commonWeightUnit,
            };
        })
        .SelectMany((fullOrderData) =>
        {
            return fullOrderData.Items.Select(x =>
            {
                return new
                {
                    TotalVolume = fullOrderData.TotalVolume,
                    TotalWeight = fullOrderData.TotalWeight,
                    TotalVolumeUnit = fullOrderData.TotalVolumeUnit,
                    TotalWeightUnit = fullOrderData.TotalWeightUnit,
                    OrderNumber = x.OrderNumber,
                    Weight = x.Weight,
                    WeightUnit = x.WeightUnit,  //string = KG
                    Volume = x.Volume,
                    VolumeUnit = x.VolumeUnit,   ////string = CUBIC-MTR
                    PackageQuantity = x.PackageQuantity,
                    PackageQuantityUnit = x.PackageQuantityUnit, // 
                    CustomerProductQuantity = x.CustomerProductQuantity,
                    CustomerProductQuantityUnit = x.CustomerProductQuantityUnit,

                };
            });
        })
        .GroupBy(co => co.OrderNumber)
        .Select(x => x.First());


double totalWeight = customerOrderResponse.First().TotalWeight; // reads 47
double totalVolume= customerOrderResponse.First().TotalVolume; // reads 31
```

Comment: The Sum method is not available in case of piping the results from the first query TotalVolume = items.Sum(x => x.Volume), // beware of unit.
TotalWeight = items.Sum(x => x.Weight), // beware of unit.

Comment: @this-Me I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that. Sum should work for any enumerable, what happens when you create a list of the items first? (see edit)

Comment: @CédricMoers, have you tried to run similar query before? From my experience it will not work. After GroupBy, you can not access items, only aggregation are allowed.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I did not run this query, only compiled it. I'll give it another look.

Comment: For me this just seems to work. Added some sample data, ran the query and it gave me the expected result.

Comment: @this-Me if you plainly copy the new test code in your project and run this, does that work? If not, can you post a screenshot of the exception? I also added a fiddle if you prefer that.

Comment: It will work with IEnumerable but not with LINQ provider.

Comment: It gets the sum of the items. However you are projecting this on a separate object. In my case I was wondering if it was possible within the first anonymous object and not on new object.   `Volume = firstData.Volume, //<---- Sum here 
                        PackageQuantity = firstData.PackageQuantity,//<------ Sum here
                CustomerProductQuantity = firstData.CustomerProductQuantity` @CédricMoers

Comment: @this-Me you would need some sort of inheritance structure, which is not supported by anonymous types unfortunately. You can define a custom class and use that instead if that is what you desire. You can also re-fill the properties in the new anonymous object. But you can also access the original items trough Items of the new object. If it is only the first item that you want, you can do Items.ElementAt(0)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I do not have experience with LINQ providers, but I do not know if that is what the question is about.

Comment: @this-Me I updated my answer to have all properties available within one (anonymous) object. Does this then solve the question?

Comment: @CédricMoers: Thanks a ton for the pointer, I modified a little bit in my code to project it in a different way and I was able to query the needed. Thanks again

Comment: @this-Me Glad I could help!